# Matlab name assignment

Tags: matlab, filenames, rename

I am trying to decrease some big chucks of matlab code i had from a while ago, and was hoping to get them a bit more "clean".

The VarName2,VarName3,VarName4 ...etc are provide by measured data and i will know what they are always going to be thus i gave me the name A,B ,C , the think i want changed though is the first part of the name, so every time i run the .m file I will use the input('') option

where as fname = 'SWAN' and A, B , C are the second part of the name and they are constant.

```
fname = input ('enter name')

fname_A = VarName2
fname_B = VarName3
fname_C = VarName4
```

and want to be getting

```
SWAN_A = VarName2
SWAN_B = VarName3
SWAN_C = VarName4
```

thank you

Following your advices I been trying the structure construction

```
S.name = input ('enter name of the data ".." ==')
S.A = A;
S.A(1,:)=[];
S.B = B;
S.B(1,:)=[];
S.C = C;
S.C(1,:)=[];
S.D = D;
S.D(1,:)=[];
S.E = E;
S.E(1,:)=[];
```

may i ask if i can also have an input thing command so i can change the name of the structure?

Precede the script with `S='west'` and then do

```
'S'.name = input ('enter name of the data ".." ==')
    S.A = A;
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Can't you simply do a replace all for `fname_a` into `SWAN_A`?

Comment: @George: dont do this, use cell arrays or structs instead: http://matlab.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ#How_can_I_create_variables_A1.2C_A2.2C....2CA10_in_a_loop.3F, http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/03/08/top-10-matlab-code-practices-that-make-me-cry/ (number 1 on the list)

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin i was doing that bu t i want to automate the process a bit its annoying to have to open the files all the time and change the name

Comment: @Amro thanks for the link but i dont want to change the structure of my data just names

Comment: If you are actually trying to change a lot of names in a lot of different files, you just need a solution for changing textfiles. This is completely independant of matlab, so you should be able to find something for it.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin: no, the OP is trying to assign variables where the name is defined at runtime! I still say don't do that, use a structure instead in this case...

Comment: @George Why would you want this? It seems like an extremely bad idea. What are you doing with `SWAN_A` etc later in your code? If you name them at run time, how do you plan on working with them later? And if you're not working with them later, why would you need them to be named like that? I think you should rethink the structure of your code here.

Comment: @Dan I can upload the code on here , the files after that go trough a process of statistical analysis and plotting, comparing them multiple time, so now i m in the process of cleaning the code a bit, revisiting old processes

Comment: It sounds to me like you are running a MATLAB script which dumps its results into your workspace, overwriting the old results, and you want to specify a unique name to be able to run multiple runs.  Instead, what you should do is turn the script into a function.  Then, when you call it, store the results into whatever variable you want.

Comment: @Peter yes its pretty close to that, i thought the solution of a function but i am not sure how to create it, correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I would probably store the information that you are handling:

```
S.name = input ('enter name')
S.A = VarName2
S.B = VarName3
S.C = VarName4
```

And if you want to do it a few times:

```
for t=3:-1:1
  S(t).name = input ('enter name')
  S(t).A = VarName2
  S(t).B = VarName3
  S(t).C = VarName4
end
```

---

In this way you could now find the struct named 'swan':

```
idx = strcmpi({S.name},'SWAN')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `eval`

```
eval( sprintf('%s_A = VarName2;', fname ) );
eval( sprintf('%s_B = VarName3;', fname ) );
eval( sprintf('%s_C = VarName4;', fname ) );
```

**Note that the use of `eval` is [not recommended](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/string-evaluation.html#bs7kmd5)**.

One alternative option may be to use struct with dynamic field names:

```
A.( fname ) = VarName2;
B.( fname ) = VarName3;
C.( fname ) = VarName4;
```

Now you have three structs (`A`, `B` and `C`) with `A.SWAN` equal to `VarName2`, `B.SWAN` equal to `VarName3` etc.

Comment: thanks it works fine, exactlyy what i wanted, much appreciated

Comment: I'm disappointed with you Shai for recommending bad practices (even with the warning), you know better :(

Comment: @George Don't do this, use cells or structs.

Comment: @Amro you are right. shame on me!! I was about to edit my answer to suggest a practicle method to avoid evil `eval`...

Comment: @Amro is this version better?

Comment: thank you guys i shall try the way of coding you think its better, its worth a try :)

Comment: thanks @Shai for listing an alternative to the often misused `eval`, much better now :)